# Problem separating C++ code in header, inline functions and code

Tags: c++

I have the simplest code that I want to separate in three files:

- Header file: class and struct declarations. No implementations at all.
- Inline functions file: implementation of inline methods in header.
- Code file: normal C++ code for more complicated implementations.

When I was about to implement an `operator[]` method, I couldn't manage to compile it. Here is a minimal example that shows the same problem:

Header (`myclass.h`):

```
#ifndef _MYCLASS_H_
#define _MYCLASS_H_

class MyClass
{
 public:
  MyClass(const int n);
  virtual ~MyClass();

  double& operator[](const int i);
  double  operator[](const int i) const;

  void someBigMethod();

 private:
  double* arr;

};

#endif /* _MYCLASS_H_ */
```

Inline functions (`myclass-inl.h`):

```
#include "myclass.h"

inline double& MyClass::operator[](const int i) {
  return arr[i];
}

inline double MyClass::operator[](const int i) const {
  return arr[i];
}
```

Code (`myclass.cpp`):

```
#include "myclass.h"
#include "myclass-inl.h"
#include <iostream>

inline MyClass::MyClass(const int n) {
  arr = new double[n];
}

inline MyClass::~MyClass() {
  delete[] arr;
}

void MyClass::someBigMethod() {
  std::cout << "Hello big method that is not inlined" << std::endl;
}
```

And finally, a main to test it all:

```
#include "myclass.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  MyClass m(123);
  double x = m[1];
  m[1] = 1234;
  cout << "m[1]=" << m[1] << endl;
  x = x + 1;
  return 0;
}

void nothing() {
  cout << "hello world" << endl;
}
```

When I compile it, it says:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to 'MyClass::MyClass(int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to 'MyClass::operator[](int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to 'MyClass::operator[](int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x65): undefined reference to 'MyClass::operator[](int)'
```

However, when I move the `main` method to the `MyClass.cpp` file, it works. Could you guys help me spot the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to separate inline function definitions from the header file?

Comment: Why do you want to separate it into three files? The canonical way in C++ is to use two - header file containing declarations & inline functions, implementation file containing non-inline functions etc. All you are doing is creating extra maintenance problems for you and anyone else who has to touch your code.

Comment: `_MYCLASS_H_` tsk tsk.  Names beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved (i.e., don't use them).

Comment: And BTW, your header guard names are illegal. C++ reserves names begining with an underscre and an uppercase letter for the C++ implementation - you are not allowed to create such names in your own code.

Comment: @James @Neil: thank you, actually I had never looked at the name of my define, because this was automatically generated for me by yasnippet for emacs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your main program file used to test your setup does not include the header file with the inline member functions. Since the functions are inline, they are not included in the object file produced from `myclass.cpp`.

The inline functions are not available to the compiler, so it thinks the calls are external; but they are also not available to the linker, since they do not generate standalone definitions anywhere else.

If you want the functions to be inline, just put them in `myclass.h`.

Comment: or #include "myclass.h" everywhere that you want to use the inline functions. (Juliano's answer is easier to do the bookkeeping on.)

Comment: #include "myclass.h" won't help, since they are defined in myclass-inl.h, which is not included by myclass.h.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. But what's the deal then with the google style guide and `-inl.h` files?
http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#The_-inl.h_Files

Comment: @YuppieNetworking: They likely include the `-inl.h` files at the end of the header. So in "myclass.h", the last line would be: `#include "myclass-inl.h"`

Comment: @YuppieNetworking: Don't take the Google C++ style guide at face value. They use some rationale that works well for them, but may not be true for other developers. You should learn C++ using common practices, until you know enough to understand the rationale for those directives.

Answer (score 3):

You must define inline functions in the header file, not in a different compilation unit. Otherwise, how can the compiler inline them? When the compiler sees a call for a function that is supposed to be inline it must know its definition so it can inline it rather than mark the call for the linker.

The best solution I can offer is to remove the inline keywords altogether from those functions. Inline a function only when you have concrete profiler numbers to back the decision, or when the function body is zero to one lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `myclass-inl.h` in main.cpp

Splitting code across three files is not recommended though.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is with the linking.  When you're linking the executable are you including myclass.o?  You'll need to compile this as well.